# Binding list to datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a WPF application with a datagrid. On load my ViewModel populates a list called HldChangeList. This list is bound to the data grid. The list contains approx. 200 items but at the moment the list shows 10 empty rows but no column headers. I've put a stop in my setter and can see the code is getting there. Not sure what else I am missing.

**View Model**

```
 private List<HoldingPrePost> _hldChangeList;

 public List<HoldingPrePost> HldChangeList
    {
        get
        {
            return _hldChangeList;
        }
        set
        {
            _hldChangeList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("HldChangeList");
        }
    }
```

**XAML**

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGridHoldings"  
                  DataContext="{Binding HldChangeList}" 
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                  VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                  Background="Silver"
                  RowHeaderWidth="30"  
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=HldChangeList, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                  Style="{StaticResource DataGridTemplate}"  
                  ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource DG_ColumnHeader}"                                            
                  RowStyle="{StaticResource DG_Row}"
                  CellStyle="{StaticResource DG_Cell}"                                    
                  RowHeaderStyle="{StaticResource DG_RowHeader}"
                  Margin="15,5,20,15" >
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="ABC" Binding="{Binding ABC}"  IsReadOnly="True"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="DEF" Binding="{Binding DEF}"  IsReadOnly="True"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="GHI" Binding="{Binding GHI}"  IsReadOnly="True"/>
        </DataGrid>
```

Comment: How do you populate your list? Do you load all items in one go and then do single `HldChangeList` update?

Comment: What does a HoldingPrePost look like? Also, peel back all the unnecessary things untill it works, like remove Styles, columns and make autogen columns true until it works.

Comment: yes I load all the items in one go. HldChangeList = db.GetChangeList() The GetChangeList returns list<HoldingPrePost>

Comment: I've removed all the style and column headers - just returns a blank datagrid. HoldingPrePost contains 6 properties - 4 strings & 2 doubles, nothing fancy.

Comment: What you get with AutoGenerateColumns="True"?

Comment: AutoGenerateColumns =True does nothing either

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're setting both `DataContext` and `ItemsSource` to `HldChangeList`

```
<DataGrid 
    DataContext="{Binding HldChangeList}" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=HldChangeList, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

WPF will search for `HldChangeList` items source property in current binding context which you also set to `HldChangeList` so in your case it will look for `HldChangeList.HldChangeList` property. If `HldChangeList` is already part of current binding context then you don't need to change `DataContext` otherwise you need to set it to something that contains `HldChangeList` property

**EDIT**

You forgot to enclose column definitions in `DataGrid.Columns` tag

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGridHoldings" ... ItemsSource="{Binding Path=HldChangeList}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="ABC" Binding="{Binding ABC}"  IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="DEF" Binding="{Binding DEF}"  IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="GHI" Binding="{Binding GHI}"  IsReadOnly="True"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: When I remove the ItemSource line the datagrid is still empty though. Does this mean the DataContext is not binding properly

Comment: where is `HldChangeList` defined? In `Window` or some view model?

Comment: HldChangeList is defined in my view model. I removed the datacontext and just used the ItemSource. When I did this I had an error message - "Items collection must be empty before using ItemSource"

Comment: @mHelpMe Setting the `DataContext` is not the same as setting the `ItemsSource`. You need to set the `ItemsSource` to populate the DataGrid. The `DataContext` property only sets the data object stored behind the UI object. [WPF-it's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23365736/302677) provides an example of two ways you could bind this

Comment: @mHelpMe check my edit. Error suggest that removing `DataContext` works but you forgot about `DataGrid.Columns` tag so it tries to get items from 2 sources one being `ItemsSource` and then, without `DataGrid.Columns` treats columns definitions as rows

Answer (score 2):

As dkozl said,

you need to set `ItemsSource` of your `DataGrid` explicitly without setting its `DataContext` or implicitly by setting the `DataContext`

**Implicit**

```
   <DataGrid ... 
          DataContext="{Binding HldChangeList}" ... 
          ItemsSource="{Binding}" ... />
```

**Explicit**

```
   <DataGrid ... 
          ItemsSource="{Binding HldChangeList}" ... />
```